# How to add custom CSS files for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm using Rails 7 with Tailwind and ran `rails new myapp --css tailwind` which created `app/assets/stylesheets/application.tailwind.css`

How do you add a custom CSS file so not all our CSS is in this one file? I tried adding  this file but don't know how to link it

`app/assets/stylesheets/header.css`

```
#header {
    @apply p-2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place `@import` on top of `application.tailwind.css` file.

So in your case it should be like that:

```css
@import "header.css";

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Also [this link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/using-with-preprocessors#build-time-imports) might be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Create a new file under `app/assets/stylesheets` for `header.css`

in `app/assets/config/manifest.js` add a link for headers.css

```
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_tree ../builds
//= link headers.css
```

In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb` add an entry for headers in the existing stylesheet_link_tag

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", "headers" "data-turbo-track": "reload" %>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can add custom css inside the application.tailwind.css file e.g.

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;


@layer base {
   #header {
     @apply p-2;
  }
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-css-and-layer

Answer (score -1):

Same problem here. I was using TailwindCSS with the `cssbundling-rails` gem.

Solved like this:

- add the `sassc-rails` gem
- create a custom file in `app/assets/stylesheets/custom.scss` (you can use another name)
- add `//= link custom.css` to `app/assets/manifest.js`
- add `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'custom' %>` in the head section of your layout.

That's all!

Extra bonus: if you need to insert an image reference into your css/scss/sass file: rename this file from `custom.css` to `custom.css.erb`:

```
.wall-bg {
  background: url('<%= asset_path('wall.png') %>') gray;
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```